# Trying to implement 2.2.2 with Google Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update my site to the latest version with Google API v3 and I cam getting errors.

Screenshot:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pooteofpqcpjxsw/Screenshot%202014-11-21%2016.45.41.png?dl=0

Here is the link to the page
http://stmonicaindy.org/school/family-calendar/

I am not sure what the problem is. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Shawn

Comment: Here are the links which will be helpful for the migration.https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration#calendars. Calendar V3 uses Oauth 2.0 and here is the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth.Let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: I should say that this is specifically using the fullcalendar script from http://fullcalendar.io/.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a problem with this myself.  I am guessing you looked at this page?

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

The other thing, if you have done this is to make sure you have the right referees in place in the credentials section.

For example (on two separate lines):
    `www.fireflytheatre.com`
    `*fireflytheatre.com*`

```
The stars are important.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Now I am getting this error-- Google Calendar API: Access Not Configured. The API is not enabled for your project, or there is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your configuration.  -- If I am on a shared IP, does that affect the count. I will double-check the domain and make sure the asterisks are there.

Comment: For this error please make sure that you enabled Calendar API for your project in the developer console.

Comment: I have enabled it already.[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/l26sxrcm3bv1woo/Screenshot%202014-11-26%2009.44.14.png?dl=0   And I just set a test up on a site that has a dedicated IP. [link]http://socc.org/cal/demos/gcal.html